# I need to send a UDP packet from the ethernet adapter to an FPGA with a known MAC address and ipv4 address

Tags: python, sockets, networking, udp, ethernet

I need to send a UDP packet over ethernet from 169.254.xx.xx to 192.168.xx.xx. The second address is the address of the FPGA and its MAC address is known. I am using wireshark to monitor the packets, but when i have an unbound socket, and I call `sock.sendto()` it sends over WLAN. When I bind the socket to the WLAN interface, it sends, but when I bind the socket to the ethernet interface, I get this error when I try to send:

```
OSError: [WinError 10051] A socket operation was attempted to an unreachable network
```

When bound to the ethernet interface, and i send to an unused address in the 169.254.xx.xx subnet, it sends an ARP, but nothing is sent when the destination is in the 192.168.xx.xx subnet.

Here is the code:

```
import socket
import time

address = '192.168.1.239'
port = 1235
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
sock.bind(('169.254.190.73', 0))

sock.sendto('100'.encode('utf-8'), (bytes(address, 'UTF-8'), port))
time.sleep(0.005)

sock.close()
''' 
   '''
```

Comment: `'169.254.190.73' != '192.168.1.239'` Adapter say `No active connection!`

Comment: And if haven't any idea about `metrics` bind to socket `"0.0.0.0"` address !

Comment: @dsgdfg binding to "0.0.0.0" doesn't seem to work

Comment: 169.x.x.x and 192.y.y.y are different network, need routing. Also, 169.x.x.x is an automatic IP for unconfigured network cards (no DHCP, no manual config), you should have a look at your pc´s network config.

Comment: Dear friend, low level communication never used an `IP` like on the processor(IP required `IPv4` or `IPv6` connection). Low level(hardware level) things required `RAW` connection, so need using only `MAC`. Other things (ipv4,ipv6) got a lot security bugs. You waste processor clock for `never used data` and never reached to `1us or 2us` delay !

Answer (score 1):

Since 169.254.xx.xx and 192.168.xx.xx represent different networks, traffic in between needs to be routed. However, 169.254.0.0/16 (autoconf) isn't usually routed.

If both nodes actually reside in the same layer 2 segment, just (manually) change the autoconf client's IP address.